# Получить тип документа из поля с полным именем

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица `Documents` с полем `DOC_FNAME` в котором хранятся полные имена документов с их типом.

Например:

```
+---------------+
|abrahadabra.pdf|
|---------------|
|some.txt       |
|---------------|
|Doc.docx       | 
+---------------+
```

Нужно запросом по получить тип документа, чтобы было так:

```
+------+
|.pdf  | 
|------|
|.txt  |
|------|
|.docx | 
+------+
```

Пробую так:

```
SELECT  ( SELECT (substr( d.DOC_FNAME, length(d.DOC_FNAME) - instr('.', d.DOC_FNAME)+1)) FROM dual) AS doctype                        
FROM Documents d
GROUP BY d.DOC_FNAME;
```

но нужный результат я не получаю. Прошу помощи.

Comment: попробуйте вместо  `( SELECT (substr( d.DOC_FNAME, length(d.DOC_FNAME) - instr('.', d.DOC_FNAME)+1)) FROM dual)` просто условие `substr(d.DOC_FNAME, instr('.', d.DOC_FNAME))`

Comment: попробовал. возвращает полное имя файла

Comment: Я ошибся. Попробуйте `substr(d.DOC_FNAME, instr(d.DOC_FNAME, '.'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select substr(DOC_FNAME,-instr(reverse(DOC_FNAME),'.'))
  from table
```

Обратите внимание на функцию reverse, она разворачивает строку задом наперед, что бы получить позицию именно последней точки, ведь в современных именах файлов точек может быть несколько. Функция substr умеет отрезать от конца строки, для этого используется отрицательная позиция.

Вариант 2, с использованием регулярных выражений (для Oracle 10g+):

```
select regexp_substr(DOC_FNAME,'\.[^.]*$')
  from table
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, действительно перепутал теги. Я использую Oracle

Comment: @LocalUser Я поправил ответ для Oracle ...

Comment: Ваш вариант возвращает возвращает полное имя файла, не обрезает до типа.

Comment: @LocalUser Вы там минус перед instr не забыли случайно ? я проверял у себя на Oracle, все отлично работает.

Comment: странно. с минусом и без - возвращается один и тот же результат. Буду разбираться почему

Comment: @LocalUser посмотрите что instr возвращает, должна 4 (для .pdf). Или второй, только что написанный, вариант попробуйте, там ломаться нечему

Comment: @0xdb Исправил :)